# Xcode Organizer Console: What is House Arrest

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoa-touch

I'm working on an iPhone app using Amazon Web Services uploading videos to S3. I can have small sized videos or large size videos. During the uploading process, sometimes it will come to a complete hang and just stall without any errors or timeout exceptions. In the organizer console for debugging in Xcode, I get a bunch of errors about house arrest max files open 125. Can anyone tell me what this means and if could have anything to do with why I'm having upload problems?

```
 May  6 17:37:26 taga-iPhone mobile_house_arrest[56164] <Error>: Max open files: 125
```

Comment: Can you post some of the code -- the error is pretty clear that too many files are open -- are you sure you don't have a loop opening files somewhere?

Comment: Honestly I wouldn't know what code to put up here. I'm having a big issue finding how this is happening, whether it's a memory issue, theading issue, wifi/3g signal issue. I'm not sure. I'm going to try to do more test with xcode instruments.

Comment: You could try removing or disabling code until the error disappears -- that should narrow it down some.

Comment: This is happening because you don't close opened files. Very simple.

Comment: Happens in my app too, but on install (from Xcode), but isn't fatal to it. (Shows the error 28 times.) @Sulthan, what kind of open files do you mean, and how can we affect the number of files in install?

Answer (score 0):

I have experienced the same problem.
The main problem was memory management. Do you use ARC ?

Try to run Product -> Profile -> Leaks This could help you to identify the problem.